# Axes not showing up in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating a bar chart in d3 and it seems that the execution of the javascript is getting hung up on creating the axis and as a result no axis is showing up and console logs don't work after I create the axis. Here is my code:

```
req.onload=function() {
    const dataset = json.data;
    const w = 880;
    const h = 440;
    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear();
    yScale.domain([0,d3.max(dataset, (d) => d[1])]);
    yScale.range([10,h]) // axis will start at 10

    const svg = d3.select('body')
                  .append("svg")
                  .attr("width", w)
                  .attr("height", h);

    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .select("body")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", (d, i) => {
          return i * 3.2;
        })
        .attr("y", (d) => {
          return (h - yScale(d[1]));
        })
        .attr("width", 3.2 * .95)
        .attr("height", (d, i) => {
          return (yScale(d[1]));
        })
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .append("title")
        .text((d) => {
          return d[0];
        })

    console.log('one') // logs

    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);  // PROBLEM 
    console.log('two')  // won't log
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    console.log('three') // won't log

    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(100,50)")
        .call(yAxis);

    console.log('four'); // won't log
  };
  console.log('this will log')
});
```

It seems that calling axisBottom() is the problem but I'm not sure why. The d3 documentation isn't very detailed, but it says that the function is d3.**axisBottom**(*scale*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truly a foolish error. xAxis was not defined. I was developing this in codepen and as such wasn't seeing console error messages. Decided to create a file and open it in chrome and solved in a second. Lesson here is avoid codepen for debugging.